# How to narrow down a time(r)-based bug

Tags: android

I have a module here that has the job to smooth some UI output. It is fed by data that is timestamped. The module itself has a timer that, along with lots of code, makes sure that on the other end there is a nice visual result.

But sometimes, the whole thing gets stuck. Its extremely hard to reproduce and so far i could narrow down some things.
1) the input is still working and fine
2) the device is still responsive

So somehow the logic of the smoothing has a bug that under certain conditions hangs the thing up. I logged all "returns" because its still drawing stuff, but the values dont seem to change, so the chain has to be cut off somewhere.

Every return statement in the code makes sense and they are called every once in a while for legitimate reasons and they dont break the code. But there has to be a combination of events/things/values that break it.

The code itself is poorly written (by some intern, who now has no clue what he did back in the day), almost no documentation and i have a HARD time understanding the code and im not a dummie.

The module "works" and we dont know if the bug has been there always or if it was introduced one day by some other changes. Time is pressing, unit testing is nonexistant.
I know it should be different, but thats just real life.

Now there's always the rewrite... But how could i first try to narrow down on the bug and maybe save myself a lot of trouble and just FIX it with some quick-n-dirty ?! (maybe its not even dirty at all and i just fix the missing 1% to 100% working)

I have no experience with unit testing and i dont really know what kind of time we are talking about to set up a test in this case. I am far beyond the ideal conditions, its more like Schwarzenegger in the movie Predator.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: It's very difficult to approach this with only abstract information. Can you provide something more concrete in how the mechanism works? Is it a background task? In a service? It sounds to be some sort of race condition. Perhaps a good place to begin is synchronize the threads to that no concurrency can exist and check that the problem persists.

Comment: how it works ? simple pojo with a timer and lots of code. If its a race condition, how do i find out where ? just sync-ing everything might lead to a real dead-lock

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, sometimes it takes much more time understanding and reverse engineering someone else's code, than writing your own version from scratch. In the past I've decided to rewrite complete programs myself, reducing the code sometimes by 80% and resulting in much more elegant and readable code. This might be impossible if we're talking about a huge project.

Some important things to have in mind though are:
- do you know the algorithm, or would you first have to reverse engineer it
- is rewriting the code doable with your skills in a reasonable time
- do you need to maintain the code often

Also, if the code was written by an inexperienced programmer, chances are that you'll find more bugs in the future.

It is impossible to give you precise advice, with the little information you give us. Use your best judgement, rewrite parts of the code if possible, split the code in different classes, modularize, rename variables, clean it up... and the bug will probably become much more evident.

Comment: if i just rewrite part of it, maybe i fix something that actually kept it going.

Comment: Philosophical question: Would that be a bad thing?